# BASH Variable changes value with combined with string value

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script that will look for all .txt files in a folder, grab the basename and then relocate the file. However, I'm having an issue where any time I try to combine the filename with a string, it outputs the "*.txt" wildcard from the for loop instead of the actual file it found. If I simply echo the variable, it outputs the expected filename.

I've included a simplified script below and the output it produces. I'm new to BASH and I assume this has something to do with the way it handles variables. I've been searching for an explanation for a few hours, but I haven't really come up with anything. Can anyone explain why the value changes when concatenated?

Here is the example code:

```
TEMP_PATH=C/Test

for testFile in $TEMP_PATH/*.txt; do
    testFileName=$(basename "$testFile")
    echo $testFileName
    echo "FileName:$testFileName"
done
```

Here is the example output from each echo

```
TestOne.txt
FileName:*.txt
```

Here are the files in the directory. TestingToo.sh is the script shown above

```
TestingToo.sh  TestOne.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results. When I run your script in described environment I got `TestOne.txt
FileName:TestOne.txt` as expected

Comment: Hmm. I just tried copying my script exactly as I have it written here and ran it again. It still produces the same output for me. 

It would be strange, but I wonder if it's related to me running this on a windows system. I've tried with both git bash, and the windows 10 developer bash. Both produce the same results...

Comment: Are you sure you have some txt files under C/Test? If not, the string $TEMP_PATH/*.txt **will not** expand into list of files under C/Test. It will be taken "as is", so you will end up with variable `testFile` set to `C/Test/*.txt`. Next command will set `testFileName` to `*.txt`. Then, in the first echo command bash will substitute `*.txt` into set of matching files, that is: `TestOne.txt` in your current directory. But in the second echo comand there will be no file matching `FileName:*.txt` pattern. So bash will leave it as-is.

Comment: Yes, both the script and TestOne.txt are in C:\Test. The 3rd code block in the main post is output from an ls command while in /mnt/c/Test. So it seems to recognize that C:\Test and C/Test are the same location. I also tried explicitly using /mnt/c/Test for TEMP_PATH and it produces the same output.

Comment: What output is produced by `echo C/Test/*.txt` command?

Comment: Looks like that just produces `C/Test/*.txt`

Comment: And that's your problem, which I've described in the comment above. No files -> no expansion. Remember, that for bash files named 'test', 'Test' and 'TEST' are three different file names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMP_PATH=~/temp
TARGET_PATH=~/temp2

filenames=`find "$TEMP_PATH" -name "*.txt" `

if [ -z "$filenames" ] ; then echo "files not found" ; exit ; fi

for testFile in $filenames; do
    testFileName=$(basename "$testFile")
    echo $testFileName
    mv "${testFile}" "${TARGET_PATH}/${testFileName}"
done
```